# Add class to all <tr> by clicking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

With this code, i get all the checkboxes checked:

```
$(".checkAllCheckboxes").click(function()
{
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

With this, i add a class to the  element, where the checkbox is in.

```
$(function()
{
    $('.table_row_checkbox').on('change',function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) 
        {
            $(this).parents('tr').addClass("checkbox_checked_row");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("checkbox_checked_row");
        }
    });
});
```

How can i add that class, in my first code, to all the  elements, by clicking select all checkboxes?

---

Sorry, i dont mean that.

My generated table code looks like:

```
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 1px; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" class="checkAllCheckboxes" /></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">ID</td>
      <td class="left">Név</td>
      <td class="left">E-mail</td>
      <td class="left">Telefonszám</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Dátum</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Státusz</td>
      <td class="right">Műveletek</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="sor55">
      <td class="left"><input class="table_row_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectedRows[]" value="55" /></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">55</td>
      <td class="left">Nagy Andrea</td>
      <td class="left">andi99@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="left">06 70 8382 11</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">2016-08-13 20:33</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; color:#ff0000">Új üzenet</td>
      <td class="right"><a href="beerkezett-uzenet.php?id=55"><span class="btn btn-sm button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span></a> <a id="55" href="#" class="deleteLink"><span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sor54">
      <td class="left"><input class="table_row_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectedRows[]" value="54" /></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">54</td>
      <td class="left">Nagy Andrea</td>
      <td class="left">andi99@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="left">06 70 8382 11</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">2016-08-13 20:33</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; color:#ff0000">Új üzenet</td>
      <td class="right"><a href="beerkezett-uzenet.php?id=54"><span class="btn btn-sm button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span></a> <a id="54" href="#" class="deleteLink"><span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the first , theres the select all checkbox.

Comment: Please post MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".checkAllCheckboxes").click(function()
{
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
      if($(this).is(":checked")) 
    {
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("checkbox_checked_row");
    } 
    else 
    {
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("checkbox_checked_row");
    }
         
    });;
});

$('.table_row_checkbox').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) 
    {
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("checkbox_checked_row");
    } 
    else 
    {
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("checkbox_checked_row");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 1px; text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox" class="checkAllCheckboxes" /></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">ID</td>
      <td class="left">Név</td>
      <td class="left">E-mail</td>
      <td class="left">Telefonszám</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Dátum</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Státusz</td>
      <td class="right">Műveletek</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="sor55">
      <td class="left"><input class="table_row_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectedRows[]" value="55" /></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">55</td>
      <td class="left">Nagy Andrea</td>
      <td class="left">andi99@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="left">06 70 8382 11</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">2016-08-13 20:33</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; color:#ff0000">Új üzenet</td>
      <td class="right"><a href="beerkezett-uzenet.php?id=55"><span class="btn btn-sm button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span></a> <a id="55" href="#" class="deleteLink"><span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sor54">
      <td class="left"><input class="table_row_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selectedRows[]" value="54" /></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">54</td>
      <td class="left">Nagy Andrea</td>
      <td class="left">andi99@gmail.com</td>
      <td class="left">06 70 8382 11</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">2016-08-13 20:33</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; color:#ff0000">Új üzenet</td>
      <td class="right"><a href="beerkezett-uzenet.php?id=54"><span class="btn btn-sm button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></span></a> <a id="54" href="#" class="deleteLink"><span class="btn btn-sm btn-danger "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you're welcome @TakácsZoltán, please upvote answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Or, slightly shorter, see here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mte7er64/3/) (edited):

```
$(".checkAllCheckboxes").click(function()
{
    $(this).closest('table').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)
    .closest('tr').toggleClass('selected',this.checked)
});
```

The function does both, set the tickmarks and assigns/removes the classname to the parent-`tr`s. As it turns out, the `.not(this)` and later `.addSelf()` were not even necessary to achieve the intended effect. I therefore removed them again ("Write less, do more").

- `.closest()` is advantageous in cases where there might be nested tables (`.parents()` would find all parent tables)
- `.closest('tr')` gets the `tr`s you want to work on.

Well, the above does not quite do everything. It does not do the `tr`-class-handling when clicking on a "normal" checkbox. The [following](https://jsfiddle.net/mte7er64/6/) does:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function()
 { var jqobj=$(this);             
   if (jqobj.hasClass('checkAllCheckboxes')) // extend the selection
   { jqobj=jqobj.closest('table').find('input:checkbox'); }
   jqobj.prop('checked', this.checked).closest('tr')
        .toggleClass('selected',this.checked);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**this can also be used to acheive the same**

```
$(".checkAllCheckboxes").click(function(){

if($(this).is(':checked')){
         $(this).parents('tr').addClass('checked');
         $('tbody tr').addClass('checked')
         $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true)
         }
     else{
         $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('checked');
         $('tbody tr').removeClass('checked')
         $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false)    
     }
});
```